# Send file via Teams (like MAPISendMail)

Tags: winapi, microsoft-teams

My (editor-like) Windows desktop program can create a new e-mail with the current project attached using MAPISendMail. A customer wants the same functionality for Microsoft Teams.

For the web version, I *think* I can probably do that with [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

But I can't find anything for the desktop app version. Is there a way to do that?

Bonus:
It would be great if the user could manually specify recipient + body text **in Teams** (and not in my program).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question a little. Are you saying you want the ability to upload a file to Teams, like into a "Files" tab? If so, yes, the Graph is the place to look. Are you wanting instead to -notify- a user or team that a file exists? Something else entirely?

Comment: I want to create a new teams message and attach a local file to that message. And then allow the user to specify recipient+text.

Comment: @leku98743, check if you are looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-file-attachments).

Answer (score 0):

So you can't actually attach files to messages directly - you basically upload the file to a web location, and then provide a *link* to the file in the message. As an example, you can upload to the SharePoint document library that exists in the "Files" tab (something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)). Then, in terms of sending the message, you can send to a Team/Channel quite easily using a [Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook). This does *not* support @mentions the moment though. Another option is to use [Graph to send the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-file-attachments).

If you're wanting instead to send a kind of 'private' message to the user, you'd need to look into creating a bot, and sending a 'Proactive' message